# How is ESPRIT pronounced?

Tags: radar

I'm implementing high resolution DOA algorithms including ESPRIT for radar systems. The word ESPRIT is obviously an acronym but, even so, how is it pronounced? Is the second i long like "ESPREEE" as the French would pronounce it or is it a short second i?

Comment: Given that it is an acronym, with the last T standing for "Techniques", I would pronounce it with a hard T. I doubt anyone really cares of how you pronounce it to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

ESPRIT, like the French word.

For two reasons:

1. Out of vanity of myself, I learned it like that, I used it in presentations like that, and all I need for that to be correct is for a majority to recognize it to be correct. Hence, by stating this publicly, I make it correct! (just kidding, but when you look at language, there's no right or wrong – there's only conventions)
2. A. Paulraj himself pronounces it French [in this presentation](https://youtu.be/gQNtiNEi3GE?t=1160), and he should know :)

So, I disagree with @Envidia on how it's pronounced, but I agree with them on: It doesn't really matter.